# VHDL/vivado syntax errors

Tags: vhdl, vivado

> Write a VHDL module for the Parallel-in, Parallel-out right-shift
>   register of Figure (attached), but add an active-low asynchronous
>   clear signal ClrN. Do not use individual flip-flops in your code.
>   Simulate the module to obtain a timing diagram similar to Figure
>   (attached).
>
> Please use parameters listed below for the waveform generations.
>
> -set ClrN = 1 for 3.5 clock cycles, = 0 for the next half clock cycle, = 1 for rest fo test.
>
> -set L = 1 for 5 clock cycles, = 0 for the next 3 clock cycles, = 1 for the rest of the test
>
> -set SI = 1
>
> -set D = 0101
>
> -set Sh = 0 for 1 clock cycle, = 1 for the next 5 clock cycles, = 0 for the rest of the test
>
> Submit simulation waveforms that demonstrate the operation of your
>   code.

I get error `[Synth 8-1789] cannot update 'in' object dout`

I've tried the following:

```
library ieee;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;

entity insertname is
port (
    SI, Clk, ClrN, Sh, L : in std_logic;
    Din : in std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
    SO : out std_logic;
    Dout : std_logic_vector (3 downto 0)
);
end entity insertname;

architecture behavioral of insertname is
    signal temp: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0) := "0000";
begin
    process (Clk, ClrN)
    begin
        if ClrN = '0' then
            temp <= x"0";
        elsif Clk'event and Clk = '1' and Sh = '1' then
            temp <= SI & temp(3 downto 1);
            SO <= temp(0);
        elsif Clk'event and Clk = '1' and Sh = '0' and L = '1' then
            temp <= Din;
        elsif Clk'event and Clk='1' and Sh='0' and L='0' then
            temp <= temp;
        end if;
    end process;
Dout <= temp;
end behavioral;
```

[Figures mentioned above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2oyC.png)

Comment: The [linked figures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2oyC.png) are from *Fundamentals of Logic Design* 6th ed. by Charles H. Roth, Jr. and Larry L. Kinney, pages 360-361. Note you've made SO a separate flip flop. You can also express the multiplexers  shown in front of the flip flops in Figure 12.10 (b) as an inner if statement. You don't need to assign a value to itself in a sequential element (register, flip flops).  Note Table 12-1 doesn't show it. Your shift assignment appears incorrect from Figure 12-10(b).

Answer (score 4):

To fix the syntax error, check the port list in your entity declaration: The `Dout` signal should be defined as `out` like this:

```
Dout : out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0)
```

As noted by user1155120, *IEEE Std 1076-2008, 6.5.2 Interface object declarations* states:

> If no mode is
>   explicitly given in an interface declaration other than an interface
>   file declaration, **mode in is assumed.**

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008, 6.5.2 Interface object declarations "If no mode is explicitly given in an interface declaration other than an interface file declaration, mode **in** is assumed."

Comment: @user1155120 Thanks, good to know in the future. I have always defined the mode explicitly so this hasn't been an issue.